# How to query certain point based on specific time, and if no value then take the nearest time in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

Is it possible to query a certain measuring point based on time, and if there is no such point, then take the nearest one in Apache IoTDB? What I want to query out is a specific value at a certain time. If no value is matched, then take the latest value. I wonder how should I write my sql statement using the `last` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `select last status, temperature from root.ln.wf01.wt01 where time <= 2017-11-07T23:50:00`. This statement will let you know the nearest data point for the time you want in Apache IoTDB.